# COM Server with only one running instance (Service, Singleton, ...)

Tags: c#, .net, com, service

for a third party application I need to program a Com Server. This is no problem but I need the COM Server to run only in one instance. This instance should run as a service  so that it is not created every time new.

The COM Application is created by vbs every time new.

```
Dim myCom
Set myCom = Nothing                                                   
Set myCom = CreateObject("MyCom.Application")
myCom.DoAction
```

The Com Server itself creates a database connection and I want to connect once and not for every creation.

I hope you understand what I mean. If not contact me pleade via comment. Thanks.

Chris

Comment: If what you mean is "I want multiple MyCom.Application" but only ever one DatabaseConnection to exist - then try this: Create a Static class that has a static constructor. In the ctor create an instance of your DatabaseConnection.  For any/all MyCom.Application instances, you can call the static class to access it's single database connection.  NOTE: Is this REALLY the behaviour you want though?  So all users hit the same connection all the time? If so, then you'll almost certainly want to implement a lock/pool/queue system so that users wait for the connection to free up before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ExeCOMServer](https://cfx.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Visual%20Studio%202008/CSExeCOMServer/ExeCOMServer.cs):

> ExeCOMServer encapsulates the skeleton of an out-of-process COM server in
>   C#. The class implements the singleton design pattern and it's thread-safe. 
>   To start the server, call CSExeCOMServer.Instance.Run(). If the server is 
>   running, the function returns directly.